# Trying to connect to AWS RDS from an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to an AWS RDS instance from an AWS EC2 instance. I ssh into the AWS EC2 instance, and then issue the following command:

```
mysql -h xxxxxx.ciy4oapkpytm.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root -p
```

and when I enter my password, I get the following:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-xxx-xxx-50.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)
```

The ip address: 10.xxx.xxx.50 is already in my RDS instance security group.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add MySQL permissions for that user/box combination. There are a million other answers on this site & a google search away for this...

Comment: I need to be able to connect to the AWS MySQL RDS instance before I can create permissions, hence my question.